# How to show all child data from firebase but exclude specific child inside a recycleview?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing my project where the function is user can select a time slot from tutor that showing in a recycleview. The tutor also is a user, so i want to implement a function that can retrieve data(time slot) except the data(time slot) from who are searching. The related query method is orderbyChild().equalTo(), but i know it cant use for inequality.

I set "TimeSlotsRef" as DatabaseReferences object to getInstances and getReference from child("TimeSlots").

For now i only can set query as "TimeSlotsRef" to show data inside recycleview, so can someone provide me a **query method to retrive all data from a child except data from a specific nested child?**

Below is my code:

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

   TimeSlotsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Time Slots");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TimeSlots> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TimeSlots>()
                    .setQuery(TimeSlotsRef, TimeSlots.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TimeSlots, TimeSlotViewHolder> adapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TimeSlots, TimeSlotViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TimeSlotViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull TimeSlots model)
            {
                holder.txtTutorName.setText(model.getTutorID());
                holder.txtTutorTime.setText(model.getStartTime() + " - " + model.getEndTime());
                holder.txtTutorDate.setText(model.getDate());
                holder.txtArea.setText(model.getArea());
                holder.txtTutorPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
                holder.txtTutorSubject.setText(model.getSubject());
                holder.txtLevel.setText(model.getLevel());
                holder.txtCategory.setText(model.getCategory());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getTutorImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.blank_profile).into(holder.tutorImage);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SpecificTimeSlotDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("timeSlotID", model.getTimeSlotID());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public TimeSlotViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tutor_item_layout, parent, false);
                TimeSlotViewHolder holder = new TimeSlotViewHolder(view);

                return holder;
            }
        };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening(); }
```